# How to implement a handle efficiently in thread safe C-library

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization, shared-libraries, c99

I have a rather complex C99 conform shared library. It contains a large number of global variables and many short functions, but only a few are used by the user directly.

I'd like to refactor it into a thread-safe library. To do that, I would make the user pass a handle to each function. The handle would be a pointer to a struct which contains what were previously global variables.

Performance is important in this case and I don't want to jeopardize it. What do I need to be careful about when implementing handles? For example, a typical function looks like this

```
void calculate(){
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){   
        particle[i].x += G * particle[i].y;
        other_function_that_does_something_to_particle();
    }
}
```

Naively, I would add a handle like this

```
void calculate(struct Handle* h){
    for (int i=0; i<h->N; i++){   
        h->particle[i].x += h->G * h->particle[i].y;
        other_function_that_does_something_to_particle(h);
    }
}
```

which looks rather inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of passing pointers is typically marginal. It has higher impact on architectures, where parameters are passes through stack and somewhat smaller when parameters are passed through registers.

Use `const` pointers (pointers to const data). Use `volatile` field or pointer specifiers when the data can modified by other threads. And use `restrict`.

All type specifiers have certain impact. For example, when processing multiple references without `restrict`, the compiler might be forced to re-read values even if it has already read them. And so on.

Worth to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict

Comment: Unless shared by threads, there is no need for `volatile`. A `const` pointer is a constant pointer, not a pointer to constant data.

Comment: In the above example, does it make sense to locally cache constants, e.g. `const double _G = h->G`?

Comment: @hanno: I would first try without. Leave optimizations to the compiler first. Modern compilers like gcc often know better than you what to do for their target architecture. Only **if** performance is not sufficient, identify hot-spots and optimize by hand.

Comment: Yes, it has a sense. Compiler is not always capable of figuring out that `h->G` is different from `h->particle[i].x`. But if it does, then extra variable has no effect.

Comment: @Olaf if the `h->particle` is a pointer, then compiler would not be able to optimize it. If it is a member array, then it would.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk: it might as well break optimization and result in even worse code. I'd say don't in the first place. There is a general rule not to do any premature optimizations which make code more complex.

Answer (score 2):

That is not necessarily slower. On some architectures it can even be faster as they have to load the address of global variables into a register anyway (e.g. ARM). Just check the PCS and ABI for your platform to make sure how arguments are passed best so you pass the handle/context pointer in a register.

I would make `h` itself constant, however: `struct Handle * const h`. This prevents `h` from being modified by accident.

If you can move to C11, have a look at _Thread_local storage class specifier. This might be what you want. If a manual implementation might be more efficient, depends on your system, however.